# Is it possible to return a table with some constraint in another .php page in ajax and show it in div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when i click the today button, it goes to **updatetoday.php** page where i select a query and display it in call back of an ajax and display the table in .php file to div with id #test. but it display's error as **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#today').click(function()
    {
        alert("hi");
        $.ajax({
                            url:'updatetoday.php',
                            data:{update:today}, // pass data 
                            success:function(result)
                            {$( "#test" ).html(result);}
                            });

    });
    });
```

**updatetoday.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("error connecting1...");
mysql_select_db("cubitoindemo",$conn) or die("error connecting database...");
if($_GET['update']==today) //taking
{

    echo "<table align='center' border='1' cellspacing='2'><tr><th>Book_id</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Start Date</th><th>Source</th><th>Destination</th><th>Morning Time</th><th>Evening Time</th><th>Duration</th><th>Days Off</th><th>Date Off</th><th>Current Status</th><th>Call Counter</th><th>Option</th><th>Calender</th><th>Save</th></tr><br><br><br>

    <?php
    $query_book = 'Select * from `booking` where validity = 1 limit 5';
    $result_book = mysql_query($query_book);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_book))
    {
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        // query for customer table
        $query_cus = 'Select * from `customer` where user_id = $user_id limit 5';
        $result_cus = mysql_query($query_cus);  
        $row_cus = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_cus);
        $name = $row_cus['user_id'];
        $email = $row_cus['email_id'];
        $mobile_number = $row_cus['mobile_number'];
        $current_status = $row['valid'];
        $startdate = $row['start_date_timestamp'];
        if($current_status == '1')
        {
            $status = '<p style='color:green;font-weight:600;font-size:19px'>Reg</p>';
        }
        else if($current_status == '2')
        {
            $status = '<p style='color:green;font-weight:600;font-size:19px'>New</p>';
        }
        else if ($current_status == '3.1' )
        {
            $status = '<p style='color:red;font-weight:600;font-size:19px'>R</p>';
        }
    ?>  
        <tr align='center'><td class='bookid'><?=$row['book_id']?></td><td ><?=$row_cus['name']?></td><td ><?=$row_cus['mobile_number']?></td><td ><?=$row_cus['email_id']?></td><td><?=$row['start_date_timestamp']?></td><td ><?=$row['source']?></td><td ><?=$row['destination']?></td><td ><?=$row['mor_timestamp']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['eve_timestamp']?></td><td><?=$row['duration']?></td><td ><?=$row['days_off']?></td><td ><?=$row['date_off']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['current_status']?></td ><td ><?=$row['call_counter']?></td>
        <td><select class='sel' name='select_option'><option value='NULL'>Select An Option</option><option value='taking'>Taking</option><option value='later-def'>Later Defined</option><option value='later-undef'>Later Undefined</option><option value='outofrange'>Out Of Range</option><option value='rejected'>Rejected</option><option value='norespond'>No Respond</option></select></td><td><input type='text' class='cal' size='6' disabled='disabled' value='<?=$startdate?>'/></td><td><button id='<?php echo $row['book_id'];?>' class='save'>Save</button></td></tr> 
    <?php
        }//booking table while ends
    echo '</table>';

    ?>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your problem you must change the line :

```
data:{update:today}, // pass data
```

to :

```
data:{update:'today'}, // pass data
```

in your code today is a string not a varible

Answer (score 0):

Change the line :

```
success:function(data)
```

to :

```
success:function(result)
```

You are assigning the result from the php to a variable called data and in

```
{$( "#test" ).html(result);}
```

trying to display inside the #test div a variable called result.

Comment: dude sorry its result only while ask question in stackoverflow i made that small mistake. but still it show's same **caught TypeError: Illegal invocation** @cromanelli

Comment: there´s another error in updatetoday.php </div>"; . First there is no opening tag for that </div> and second i think you want that line inside PHP and change it to echo "</div>";

Comment: ya bro i changed that and also even i tried only this <?php

if($_GET['update']==today) //taking
{
 
 echo "hi";
}
?>  but still same error @cromanelli

Comment: there is another error in if($_GET['update']==today) it should say if($_GET['update']=='today')

Comment: check my last answer , it fixes the problem